# KSQL nested json needs to save keys in mulitple rows

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Here is sample data in column **metrics**:

```
{
   "data": "[{'val': '[{'TS': '52343223486', 'val': '[{ 'param': 'abc'}]'}, {'TS': '9876543234', 'val': '[{ 'param1': 'xyz'}]'}]}]"
}
```

I need to populate each record in **multiple rows**.

**Result**:

**metrics**

```
"{"TS": "52343223486", "val": "{ "param": "abc"}"}"
"{"TS": "98765432434", "val": "{ "param1": "xyz"}"}"
```

Is there any query to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://rmoff.net/2020/05/26/working-with-json-nested-arrays-in-ksqldb-example/) you can split metrics like:

```
CREATE STREAM my_stream (
  data struct<
    val array<struct<
      ts varchar,
      val varchar
    >>
  >
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

SELECT EXPLODE(DATA->VAL) FROM my_stream EMIT CHANGES;
```

As result you can create new stream like:

```
CREATE STREAM my_metrics AS SELECT EXPLODE(DATA->VAL) EMIT FROM my_stream EMIT CHANGES;
```

P.S.
You input **must be** a valid **JSON** like:

```
{"data": {"val": [{"TS": "52343223486", "val": {"param": "abc"}}, {"TS": "9876543234", "val": {"param1": "xyz"}}]}}
```

Comment: It is not working for me. When I add Array<Struct> the stream returns nothing.

Comment: I just tested and fixed my answer. It works on my environment now.

Comment: I have updated my question a little bit. Can you please take a look and let me know it will work on that as well?

Comment: Sorry, your input is not valid JSON, and I don't know how to parse it. May be you can update your producer to ingest well formatted JSON

Comment: I just have to remove = sign and replace it with colon then it will be a json. right?

Comment: Just sure about you have valid JSON. You can use this validator  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# for exaple

Comment: I have updated my question. It is a valid json now.

Comment: This part `"[{'val': '[{'TS': '52343223486', 'val': '[{ 'param': 'abc'}]'}, {'TS': '9876543234', 'val': '[{ 'param1': 'xyz'}]'}]}]"` should be JSON too like : `{"val": [{"TS": "52343223486", "val": [{ "param": "abc"}]}, {"TS": "9876543234", "val": [{ "param1": "xyz"}]}]}`

Comment: I looked at the logs and it says that ["can't convert type. sourceType: TextNode, requiredType: array<struct<ts varchar, val varchar>>